# First foundamental form

Tags: geometry

I have the following parameterization $φ (u, v) = (u, v, uv)$ of the surface $S (z = xy)$.
The first fundamental form is the matrix represented by $(\{E, F\}, \{F, G\})$ where $E = 1 + v ^ 2$, $F = uv$, $G = 1 + v ^ 2$.
The exercise says:
"Determine first fundamental form of $S$ at the point $(1, 0, 0) ∈ S$"
Does this mean that I have to replace $u = 1$ and $v = 0$ in my matrix?
I would get the matrix $(\{1,0\}, \{0,2\})$.

Comment: The answer cannot be something else than "evidently"...

Comment: so is it correct ?